# How can I find the source or link behind a button on a form/webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a webpage I currently download data feeds from by clicking a button similar to the 'Login' button shown on this link:

http://www.cebumode.com/AMWEBLOGIN.aspx

However this button is simply a 'Download' request that starts downloading a csv report.

Versus manually visiting this page to download fresh data, I am attempting to automate the process of downloading the report to feed into my scripts, however I am unable to figure out how to determine what the link is for this 'get' request, or how to download the file directly with a wget (That is, what is the source behind the button?)

How would I go about finding out this information?

I have looked through the page source and can't find any clues on this.

Comment: It'll be done server side, so there won't be anything in the source telling you what to do

Comment: So if that is the case, it looks like I will need to contact the webmaster for this information.

Comment: @AndyHolmes That's not entirely true, you just need to manually construct the request packet from the form elements, which is not something that most people recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant bits on your page is this:

```
<form method="post" action="AMWEBLOGIN.aspx" id="form1">

     <input name="txtUsername" type="text" id="txtUsername" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14pt;width:250px;" autocomplete="off">

     <input name="txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14pt;width:250px;">

     <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Login" id="btnLogin" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:14pt;">
</form>
```

It makes a HTTP-Post request to http://www.cebumode.com/AMWEBLOGIN.aspx 
with variables txtUsername and txtPassword.

This is pretty scary by the way, as it transmits the username & password in plain-text, and probably receives the forms authentication cookie unencrypted as well.

So the wget command line is something like this:

```
wget --post-data "txtUsername=$USERNAME&txtPassword=$PASSWORD" --save-cookies cookies.txt  --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 http://www.cebumode.com/AMWEBLOGIN.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. It looks like the source for the download page has no inputs, so I'll have to play around with the example you gave to figure out how to make the request, but this is a great starting point!